# Solution for equation in degrees

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, trigonometry

I have a equation to which i would like to find out all the possible solutions

```
equation = 0.26*10^(-6) == (0.002213385187406957*Cos[x] +
      Sqrt[0.5788518208475579]*0.00007500943336167372*
      Sin[x])^2
```

```
Solutions = 
  Solve[{equation, -45 <= x <= 45}, x];
```

I tried using `Solve` and `NSolve` but it is giving me a blank list. Is it possible that no solutions exist. If so how can i plot and see that indeed there are no solutions.

```
Plot[0.26*10^(-6) /. equation, {x, -90, 90}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Equation 1"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"θ", "Γ"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

I tried to plot using the above code but it is not working. I am not sure if it is correct way to plot.

Comment: Sin and Cos can maximal have the value of 1. Therefore, replace Sin and Cos by 1. Then your RHS evaluates to 5.15496*10^-6 what is smaller than 0.26.

Comment: `Plot[(0.002213385187406957*Cos[x] + 
    Sqrt[0.5788518208475579]*0.00007500943336167372*Sin[x])^2, {x, -4,
   4}]` never reaches `0.26`.

Comment: After plotting i saw my mistake. It should be ```0.26*10^(-6)``` not ```0.26```. I'll make the edit in my question. I tried to find the solutions again with this value but it still gives me empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

equation = 
  0.26*10^(-6) == (0.002213385187406957*Cos[x] + 
       Sqrt[0.5788518208475579]*0.00007500943336167372*Sin[x])^2 // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;
```

The argument of trig functions are in radians. Use [`Degree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Degree.html) to convert

```
Solutions = Solve[{equation, -45 Degree <= x <= 45 Degree}, x]

(* {} *)
```

There are no solutions in the interval `-45 Degree <= x <= 45 Degree`

```
Plot[Evaluate[List @@ equation], {x, -90 Degree, 90 Degree},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic,
   {Automatic, Table[{a  Degree, StringForm["``°", a]}, {a, -90, 90, 15}]}}]
```

[image]

```
Solutions = Solve[{equation, -90 Degree <= x <= 90 Degree}, x]
```

[image]

Numerically,

```
Solutions // N

(* {{x -> -1.31264}, {x -> 1.36419}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
equation /. Solutions // FullSimplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

In degrees

```
solN = Solutions /. a_?NumericQ :> a/Degree // N

(* {{x -> -75.2086}, {x -> 78.1625}} *)

equation /. x -> x*Degree /. solN

(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful